# What validation for outlier detection?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability, outliers

Another general question on data science! 
Let's say I have a bunch of samples and I have to detect outliers on each sample. My data would be univariate, so I can use simple methods like standard deviation or median absolute deviation.

Now my question is: how would one do any sort of validation to see if results are coherent, especially if looking at them by eye wouldn't be an option because of the size of the data? For example to choose how many standard deviations to use to define outliers. I haven't seen any quantitative method so far. Does it even exist?

Cheers

Comment: that depends on the context. This cannot be answered in general.

Comment: how does it depend on the context? Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly you didn't define the dimension of "size of the data". Which is I think important here. E.g., you can draw a q-q plot for high-dimensional data but not that easy for many data-points.

However, when looking for a general methodology I would attack this problem from a probabilistic perspective. This will never tell you which data point is an outlier, however, it will tell you what is the probability that you have an outlier (in certain areas of your data).
I have to make two assumptions (a) you know the family of distribution your data stems from, e.g., normal or poisson (b) you can estimate the parameters of this family given a data set.

Now you can define the Hypothesis that you data is from this Distribution and the alternative Hypothesis (H0) that the data is not from this distribution. If you draw a random sample from your estimated distribution, this drawn distribution should be on average as likely to come from the distribution as your observed sample. If this is not the case

However, probably more interesting is to find the sub-space which contains the outlier. This can be done with the following empirical procedure. If you now estimate the parameters of your distribution given your by Data. You can compare the estimated distribution with the  histogram  of the seen data. This gives you for each bin of the histogram a probability that ic contains an outlier. For high dimensional data this can be checked programtically.

Comment: Ok so this is the generalization of excluding everything beyond X standard deviations from a normal distribution if I understand correctly.
And to answer you, I have to apply this to data that varies in size: from 10 to 10,000 records for each independent series.

Comment: And thanks for answering my questions CAFEBABE :) You're a big help

Comment: @Luks: yes that is exactly the idea behind six sigma. It can actually be generalized towards multi-modal distributions. However, it can get really tricky there.